# scanf doesn't read double

Tags: c

I got problems regarding the minus operation in c.

```
printf("\nPlease enter your payment:\n", userpayment);
scanf("%.2f", &userpayment);

customerchange = userpayment - totalfinal;
printf("The amount of change is %.2f\n", customerchange);
```

I declared `userpayment` and `totalfinal` as `double`.

Whenever I input the price for example; `userpayment = 2000` and the `totalfinal` is 1500, the output will always be 1500.
What is the solution to this?

This is the output:

Enter the Price of Item:
500
Enter Quantity of Item:
3
The total amount of Payment is: RM1500.00
Is this the last item?
y
Rm50 cash rebate has been given to the customer.
Total Payment before cash rebate is: 1500
Total Payment after cash rebate is 1450

Please enter your payment:
5000
Your change is RM-14500.00

Comment: Don't use doubles for currency

Comment: It'll be easier to help if we see how all the variables involved are declared.

Comment: Seriously, don't use doubles for currency. I know it's not what you asked but it's best practice is to use the minor unit with an integer type, or use a dedicated data type to represent currency. Floating point numbers are good for representing a large range of numbers that don't need to be particularly accurate. Using them for currency forces you to propagate rounding error checks and explicit rounding throughout your codebase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems with scanf and doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890748/problems-with-scanf-and-doubles)

Answer (score 5):

If "userpayment" is defined as a double, then change

```
scanf("%.2f", &userpayment);
```

to

```
scanf("%lf", &userpayment);
```

or change your variables to floats instead.

As it stands, you're scanning a float into the memory of a double, resulting in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Also note that the "." specifier is not valid in scanf, though most likely it will just be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

You have an incorrect format specifier in scanf. Read the documentation.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

You should also check the return value of `scanf` to ensure that it was able to parse what you expected it to parse.

Also, if you had read your compiler warnings you could have saved yourself the trouble of asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the format from printf, it is similar but not the same, try just replacing `%.2f` to `%lf`

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined your variable as double you should use:

```
scanf("%lf", &userpayment);
```

The f is for float values, lf (long float) for doubles.

Comment: I didn't notice the typo, thank you. I corrected it.