# warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int'

Tags: c

> ```
> char *searcharray = malloc(size);
> for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
> {
>   fscanf(filePtr, "%c", searcharray[i]);
> }
> ```

Here is my code. And Everytime i keep getting the warning message:

> warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int'

How is the variable searcharray being determined as an int?

Comment: You're dereferencing the character pointer. Try using pointer notation: `(searcharray + i)`

Comment: @abelebjt %c expects a `char*` in scanf, it " Matches a sequence of characters whose length is  specified  by  the  maximum  field  width (default  1); the next pointer must be a pointer to char, ..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### What's happening:

1. `searcharray[i]` has type `char`.
2. In a varargs function, the `char` will be promoted to an `int`.

### Your bug:

1. `fscanf` expects the variables that it will place data into to be passed by pointer.
2. So you should be doing:

   ```
   fscanf(filePtr, "%c", &searcharray[i]);
   ```

Comment: Wow.  I never new about promotion of variadic args.  Where is it specified?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: See __C 2011, Section 6.5.2.2 Functions Calls, Paragraph 6__. Notably, floats are also promoted to doubles. Which is why printf("%lf", ...); and `printf("%f", ...)` both handle doubles.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: Or perhaps this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was sitting and staring at this the longest trying to figure out what was wrong.