# Can int contain value of char?

Tags: c

Sorry about the beginners question, but I've written this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int y = 's';
        printf("%c\n", y);
        return 0;
    }
```

The compiler (Visual Studio 2012) does not warn me about possibility data-loss (like from `int` to `float`).
I didn't find an answer (or didn't search correctly) in Google.
I wonder if this because `int`'s storage in memory is 4 and it can hold 1 memory storage as `char`.
I am not sure about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A character is really represented by an integer (look at ASCII representation). Also, char is 8-bit and an int is larger (dependent on platform and not specified as a certain size).

Comment: A `char` is always 1 octet is size, and an `int` is always bigger (actual size depends on different factors, but always bigger).

Comment: In C, literal characters have type `int`: `'#'` <== a value with `int` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` is just an 8-bit integer.
An `int` is a larger integer (on MSVC 32-bit builds it should be 4 bytes).

`'s'` corresponds to the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the lower-case letter 's', i.e. it's the integer number 115.

So, your code is similar to:

```
int y = 115; // 's'
```

Comment: so I can print an integer with `%c` according to his ASCII value?
Assuming y=115, and I write this: `printf("%c\n", num)`, this would print s?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's fine. Characters are simply small integers, so of course the smaller value fits in the larger `int` variable, there's nothing to warn about.

Many standard C functions use `int` to transport single characters, since they then also get the possibility to express `EOF` (which is not a character).

Answer (score 1):

In C, all characters are stored in and dealt with as integers according to the [ASCII standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). This allows for functions such as strcmp() etc.

Answer (score 0):

Despite appearances there is no `char` anywhere in your example.

For historical reasons character constants are actually `int`s so the line

```
int y = 's';
```

is actually assigning one `int` to another.

Furthermore the %c format specifier in printf actually expects to receive an `int` argument, not a `char`. This is because the [default argument promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls) are applied to variadic arguments and therefore any `char` in a call to printf is promoted to an `int` before the function is called.