# Floating point to string representation

Tags: c, floating-point, string-formatting

Consider the following code snippet:

```
char str[1000];
float b ;
b= 0.0615;
sprintf( &(str[0]), "%1.0e", b);
```

After the execution of the last statement, I expected the `str` to contain `6.15e-2`. However, I am getting the value as  `5e-315`.

Where am I going wrong. How to get the expected value?

Comment: I'm getting 6e-002 on gcc

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/8HwFys).

Comment: Are you sure you are actually assigning the value to the variable? Your code example looks like it was copy-pasted from separate parts of the program, so maybe your real code is missing the assignment.

Comment: The problem, is general, is undefined behavior as the proper prototype from `stdio.h` did not occur.  It _is_ reproducible, albeit in a strange fashion, if the `float` is not promoted to `double` and 4 zero bytes area appended.  With `.0615` as a `double`, the 8 bytes `3faf7ceda0000000` _should_ have been passed.  Instead `000000003faf7ced` was passed and the result of `5e-315` was received by `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get two digits precision with that format string, as you specified only one digit after comma (that is the .0 part after the 1).

What works for me is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    char str[1000];
    float b ;
    b= 0.0615;
    sprintf( &(str[0]), "%.2e", b);
    puts(str);
}
```

prints **6.15e-02**

The [almighty C/C++ documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) says:

> .number:
>
> For a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be
>   printed after the decimal point (by default, this is 6).

Comment: You are linking to the "almighty" ***C++*** documentation.

Comment: I knew somebody would say that, so I edited it for you. The format itself is the same for both languages.

Comment: "C(++)" is a new syntax I haven't seen yet. Will it compete with the venerable "C/C++", or the new-comer "C\C++"?

Comment: I considered C(++)? - escaped, it would look really ugly, like C(\+\+)? -  for the regex geeks, as I am one, but I edit it to the oldie but goldie C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is you forgot including `stdio.h`.

There seems to be a mismatch between what type the compiler passes to `sprintf` and what `sprintf` actually reads (as described in [cmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24383003/908515)).

Comment: That sounds unlikely beyond belief. Since `sprintf` has an ellipsis argument, it can only ever expect `double` arguments, and `float` never.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are right. I got it wrongly. Still I think the reason is the missing include.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your compiler does not realize that `sprintf()` takes all floating point arguments as `double`s. Consequently, it passes only the 32 bits of the `float` to the function, which erroneously interpretes 64 bits as a `double`. It should work fine if you cast the `float` to a `double` before passing it to `sprintf()`.

Comment: that would violate C standard, I've never seen any compilers like that

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc But it explains precisely the observed behaviour. Probably the OP also forgot to include the `stdio.h` header, triggering implicit definition of `sprintf()` as `int sprintf();`.

Comment: but without prototype (due to forgetting the include) the compiler will assume that function uses [default arguments rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls) in which floats are always promoted to double

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Ah, thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of these details. I never use the default argument rule, you know... So, yes, we can conclude that if my answer is the correct one, then the compiler is broken. But I wouldn't put it past a special compiler to not conform to the standard perfectly. Consequently, I still believe that this answer is correct, even though it is just an educated guess at what's happening.