# Float seen as a double

Tags: c

When running this little `C` script using Xcode, I get this message:

> `Format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double" at scanf("%f", v) and scanf("%f", i).`

I don't get it, since I have not declared any `double` type variables.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char choice[10];

    float v;
    float i;
    float r;

    printf("What would you like to calculate?: ");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    printf("\nYou chose: \n""%s", choice);

    if (strcmp(choice, "r") == 0)
    { 
        printf("\nPlease enter voltage (V): \n");
        scanf("%f", v);

        printf("\nPlease enter current (I): \n");
        scanf("%f", i);

        r = v/i;

        printf("%f", r);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting that warning because you failed to pass a pointer to a float (`float*`) to the function `scanf`. The compiler tells you that it's a double because `scanf` is a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). Variadic parameters are subject to [default argument promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls) (the gist of which means that arguments of certain data types are converted to larger data types when they are passed to the function. E.g. `float` in this case is promoted to `double`).

The only way for a function in C to modify variables `v`, `i`, and `choice` is to pass them as pointers, so you need to pass pointers to `scanf`, using the `&` "address of" operator.

Your code should look like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char choice[10];

    float v;
    float i;
    float r;

    printf("What would you like to calculate?: ");
    scanf("%9s", &choice); /* this specifier prevents overruns */
    printf("\nYou chose: \n""%s", choice);

    if (strcmp(choice, "r") == 0)
    { 
        printf("\nPlease enter voltage (V): \n");
        scanf("%f", &v); /* use a pointer to the original memory */

        printf("\nPlease enter current (I): \n");
        scanf("%f", &i); /* use a pointer to the original memory */

        r = v/i;

        printf("%f", r);
    }
}
```

Note also that I used the format specifier `%9s`. That way, if the user inputs more than 9 characters, adjacent memory won't be overwritten. You have to reserve the last element of the array for the null character `\0` because strings in C end with `\0`.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't get it since I have not declared any double type variables.

When there is no visible prototype to indicate what type a function expects for a given argument, or when that argument is among a set of variadic arguments, then default argument promotion is performed on that argument.  This provides for compatibility with pre-ANSI C code that assumed such promotions were performed on *all* arguments.

In this case, `scanf()` is variadic, with this prototype:

```
int scanf(const char *fmt, ...);
```

so everything but the format is subject to default argument promotion.  For arguments of type `float`, that is a promotion to `double`, and that's where your `double` comes from.

Of course, as other answers describe, you shouldn't be passing the `float` at all, but rather a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `&` operator. For example replace `scanf("%f", v);` with `scanf("%f", &v);`. This will pass the address of the variable (instead of the value) to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write `scanf("%f", &i);` e.t.c, as you want the variable to be passed as a pointer as C has no reference type like C++