# DLL Size of 32 bit Build Function Input Arguments

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, msdn

**Hi all, This is a question about some weird behaviour I found while building a DLL.**

```
#define EXTERNC  extern "c"
#define APIEXPORTS  __declspec(dllexport)
#define STDCALL __stdcall
EXTERNC APIEXPORTS STDCALL InvokeCommand(int* c, uint8_t* buff, uint16_t opcode, double* args)
```

**Size of Args = 3*(sizeof(pointer 32bit)) + sizeof(uint16_t) = 14. BUT:** 
**Looking at the dumpbin output from this export gives the following decorated name:**

```
_InvokeCommand@16
```

**According to MSDN (I am compiling in VS cpp):**

> "Leading underscore (_) and a trailing at sign (@) followed by the
>   number of bytes in the parameter list in decimal"

**but then the name should have been ...@14 not 16. Each of the three pointers being 4 bytes, and the uint16_t being two.
Can anyone explain this behaviour?**

EDIT: InvokeMessageProcess(int*, uint8_t*, int8_t*); gave the correct behaviour of _InvokeMessageProcess@12 !! Seems inconsistent!

Comment: My bet would be alignment. 12 and 16 are aligned on 4 bytes. 14 is not.

Comment: The size of each parameter must be a multiple of 4 bytes, for alignment purposes. If the formal parameter is not an exact multiple of 4 bytes, then it is rounded up to the next multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls