# Can c declare two function with the same name, return type but different parameters

Tags: c, gcc

Why the following code can be compiled by gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func();
int func(int a) { return 1; }
int main() {
   func(10);
   return 0;
}
```

But if i add `char func();`, gcc say `conflicting types for ‘func’`

Comment: Not the same with that question. I also think it is a overload, but why gcc accept that code?

Comment: that code does not compile. i don't know which compiler or how you compiled it.`error: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
`

Comment: I use gcc (GCC) 4.9.3 and maybe the warning is not default

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not an overload, because you cannot call `func()` with no arguments. This is a special case of a single function with compatible *function declarators*, as described in the standard:

> If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function declarator that is not part of a function definition and that contains an empty identifier list, the parameter list shall not have an ellipsis terminator and the type of each parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions.

Changing return type from `int` to `char` is one way to break this rule. Another way to break it is to supply a parameter type other than `int`:

```
int func();
int func(char a) { return 1; } // Does not compile
```

If you would like to declare a function that does not take any parameters, the declarator should be as follows:

```
int func(void);
```

Now declaring a `func` that takes an `int` will result in compile-time error:

```
int func(void);
int func(int a) { return 1; } // Does not compile
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on why changing the parameter type to `char` breaks this? I tested this out with Clang 13 and while `char`, `short`, and `float` result in compile errors, `int`, `long`, `long long`, `double`, and any pointer types work fine. Signedness doesn't seem to matter. I'm not sure exactly what's going on.

Comment: I think I understand now, the concepts to understand are compatible types, default argument promotions, and how these concepts apply specifically when the called function does not have a prototype. This question was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls

Answer (score 1):

Your first declaration is K&R declaration, while the next declaration (with definition) is ANSI prototype.

It is possible to make any combination between KR decl and ANSI prototypes, if they are compatible .

The C type checker will combine both and will keep the ANSI prototype.  This is called the `composite type`.

Here is how the composite type is computed for the combination between ANSI and K&R decl:

> 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>
> 3 ... If only one type is a function type with a parameter type list (a
>   function prototype), the composite type is a function prototype with
>   the parameter type list.

To check whether 2 function declarations are compatible one must apply the rules from `6.7.6.3 Function declarators`

> 15 For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify
>   compatible return types.146) Moreover, the parameter type lists, if
>   both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use
>   of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types.

This is why your prototype can be combined with K&R decl, as they are considered compatibles.