# Why does casting this pointer change the value pointed too

Tags: c, casting

I have a function that returns an `unsigned long` that is actually a `float`.

We'll call that function `unsigned long foo()`

When I make a call to printf like this:

```
printf("%f", foo());
```

it will always print out `0.00000`

but when I cast it like this:

```
unsigned long bar = foo();
printf("%f", *((float *)(&bar)));
```

it outputs the float correctly.

Printing with `"%x"` I can see that the binary representations are different. Surprisingly the `unsigned long` version looks more like an actual floating point representation (`41ba019a` vs `40000000`)

I double checked on my system that the size of `unsigned long` and `float` are the same.

So my question is:

**How can casting the pointer like this change the value of what is being pointed to?**

Edit: The relevant part of foo() is essentially

```
unsigned long foo()
{
  float a = 22.4;
  return *(unsigned long *)(&a) ;
}
```

Comment: You're not showing us the most important thing of all. Let's see `foo()`.

Comment: The value of the unsigned long was cast from a floating point to begin with. The function can return different types depending on the argument.

Comment: So? Let's see the pertinent part.

Comment: Isn't that because a float, when passed to a function, is first promoted to a double, so printf expects a double to be printed as a float? Since foo does not return a float, the transformation is not perfomed, hence the 0.0000.

Comment: This is a really bad code. If you want the function to return different types, make it work with a `union` of all of the possible types and return it. Don't reinterpret like this. It will help to avoid issues like this and other potential UBs.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie You are correct, printing with "%llx" I can see the parts lining up as one would expect. If you post an answer I will accept unless there is a better one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because a float, when passed to a function, is first promoted to a double, so printf expects a double to be printed. Since `foo` does not return a float, the transformation is not perfomed, hence printf finds something else as parameter.

Comment: Promotion of `float` to `double` is specific to variadic functions (such as `printf()`), not all functions.

Comment: @Clifford, do you have a reference (just for my curiosity)? I didn't know.

Comment: ... ok, that's not the whole story.  `float` arguments to functions without prototypes are also promoted.  For example if you declared `void fn()` but called `fn( 1.0f )`, the argument would be promoted to `double` too.  But those are exceptions to the common case where functions are fully prototyped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls. Note does not apply to C++ where `void fn()` is the same as `void fn( void )`.