# data type confusion in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

The following code works:

```
int main(void)
{  
   float f = get_float();
   int i = round(f*100);
   printf("%i\n", i); 
}
```

Yet, error generated if coding this way:

```
printf("%i\n", round(1.21*100));
```

Output says `round(1.21*100)` is `float`. So, then why

```
int i = round(f*100);
```

is fine?

Comment: When a `float` value is assigned to `int` values, an internal conversion takes place. `round()` gives an double value, so if no conversion is performed it's value remains double. In this specified case `printf("%i\n", round(1.21*100));` no conversion is performed, so it requires '%f' specifier to print float value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you do

```
int i = round(f*100);
```

you *convert* the result of the `double` function [`round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round). The converted result is stored in the `int` variable `i`, which can be used with the format `"%i"` as it expects an `int` argument.

When you pass the `double` result of `round` directly as an argument to a format that expects an `int` you have mismatching format and argument types. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

No conversion is made in the call to `printf`, and no conversion *can* be made since the code inside the `printf` function doesn't know the actual type of the argument. All it knows is the format `"%i"`. All possible type-information is lost for variable-argument functions.

Comment: well, "no conversion is made", the default argument promotions are done nevertheless.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well since the function returns a `double` value, and the default argument promotion would be to a `double`, in this specific case no conversion is done.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the behavior of automatic type casting. In printf, automatic typecasting does not work. When you say %i, it simply expects integer, it can not convert double to integer and then print.

In assignment operation, double is converted to integer first and then it is assigned to left operand of the = operator. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of duplication, but maybe helps for a better understanding:

1. `round()` has the following prototype:

   ```
   double round(double x);
   ```

   so it returns `double`.
2. There is an *implicit conversion* from `double` to `int` in C, so writing

   ```
   int i = round(f*100);
   ```

   will convert the result of `round()` to `int`.
3. If you have a function that expects an int, e.g.

   ```
   void printMyNumber(int number)
   {
       printf("%i\n", number);
   }
   ```

   you can call it like this:

   ```
   printMyNumber(round(f*100));
   ```

   and the implicit conversion works as expected, because the compiler sees both types (the return type from `round()` and the expected argument type of `printMyNumber()`).
4. The reason this doesn't work with `printf()` is that the prototype of `printf()` looks like this:

   ```
   printf(const char *format, ...);
   ```

   so, except for the first argument, the types of the arguments are *unknown*. Therefore, whatever you pass is passed without any conversion (except for [default argument promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls)). Of course, you could use a *cast* to achieve an *explicit conversion* instead:

   ```
   printf("%i\n", (int) round(f*100)); // <- this is fine
   ```