# How does int a=65; printf("%c", a); work in c language in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, char, int

```
int a=65; 
printf("%c", a);
```

I tried it on GCC on Ubuntu I don't know the version. But it worked and I wish to know how?
Because according to me the size of char is smaller than int  and hence it shouldn't have been possible.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com check for the 65 value on here. You'll find your answer.

Comment: Please don't learn C by trial and error.  There exists undefined behavior that may make you think something works one way based on some tests, but in reality is just illegal code that can break everything in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printf` function has the following declaration:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

The first argument must be a pointer to a `char` array, but any additional arguments can be of any type, so it's not a compiler error if a format specifier mismatches the parameter (although it *is* undefined behavior).

This still works however because of what `%c` expects.  From the man page:

> If no l modifier is present, **the int argument is converted to an
>                 unsigned char**, and the resulting character is written.  If an  l
>                 modifier  is  present,  the  wint_t (wide character) argument is
>                 converted to a multibyte sequence by a call  to  the  wcrtomb(3)
>                 function, with a conversion state starting in the initial state,
>                 and the resulting multibyte string is written.

From the above passage, `%c` actually expects an `int` and converts it to an `unsigned char` for printing.  So if that's the case why does passing an actual `char` work?  That is because of **integer promotions**.  Any integer type smaller than `int` is promoted to `int` anyplace an `int` can be used.  Since `printf` is variadic it can't check the types of its arguments, so a `char` passed to `printf` will get promoted to `int` when the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

> #### 7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function
>
> ...
> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
> ...
> `c`     If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted to an
> `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.
>
> If an **`l`** length modifier is present, the `wint_t` argument is converted as if by
> an ls conversion specification with no precision and an argument that points
> to the initial element of a two-element array of **`wchar_t`**, the first element
> containing the **`wint_t`** argument to the **`lc`** conversion specification and the
> second a null wide character.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

So, `(f)printf` expects the argument corresponding to the `%c` conversion specifier to have type `int`, and will convert it to `unsigned char` before formatting and displaying.

The *value* `65` can certainly fit in an `unsigned char` (0-255), so there's no problem with the conversion there. If you pass an integer value outside that range, then I suspect the following comes into play:

> #### 6.3 Conversions
>
> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
> ...
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
> subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>60)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>60) The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.</sup>

IOW, if you pass the value `321`, it should "wrap" around back to `65` (`'A'` in ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the [default argument promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls).  Anything smaller than `int`, when passed as part of `printf`'s variable argument list, is converted to `int` before the call.  Therefore, `printf("%c", foo)` cannot tell the difference between `char foo` and `int foo`.  (However, if the *value* of the datum passed to `%c` is outside the range of `unsigned char`, the behavior is undefined.)

Comment: *the behavior is undefined* - I think it is defined, as `int` is converted to `unsigned char` according to http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm, you may be right.  I said that because of [7.21.6.1p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined" but the "correct type" for `%c` is in fact `int`.  I remain not wholly certain that "converted to unsigned char" in the text of 7.21.6.1p8 means "as-if by the algorithm in 6.3.1.3p2", however.

Answer (score 0):

It worked because it just print the the value of `65` converted to a char type in ASCII table 65 is the letter A so when you put:

```
int a = 65;
printf("%c", a); //---> a coverted to char type.
```

Check the ASCII table here [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)