# Is b a scalar object in this case?

Tags: c, arrays, object, pointers, scalar

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char b[5];
    scanf("%4s%4s", b, b);
    printf("%s", b);
}
```

What is the exact definition of a scalar object?
Is `b` a scalar object in this case?

Comment: @Ed Heal But isn't ```b``` a pointer to the base address?

Comment: In this case, `b` is an array, not just a pointer.  It would be a regular pointer if it were declared like `char* b`

Comment: @Daniel Giger Thanks.

Comment: The C11 standard is [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Please read it carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), 6.2.5 (Types)/21:

> "*Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types.47)*"
>
> 47) "*Note that aggregate type does not include union type because an object with union type can only contain one member at a time.*"

---

> "*What is the exact definition of a scalar object?*"

A scalar object is an object which only consists of a single entity, such as pointers and objects of arithmetic types.

> "*Is `b` a scalar object in this case?*"

`b` isn´t a *scalar* object as a scalar object hold only one single entity. Arrays such as `b` are "*aggregates*". The array to pointer decay in `scanf("%4s%4s", b, b);` and `printf("%s", b);` doesn´t change that `b` is still of array type.

Comment: "If a side effect on a *scalar object* is unsequenced relative to another side effect on the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined." — So this doesn't apply here in the case of the statement ```scanf("%4s%4s", b, b);``` since ```b``` is not a scalar object, right?

Comment: @NirajRaut Exactly.

Comment: supports Monica Celio Thanks.

Comment: C99 Standard: "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression" — So was this definition by the C99 standard incomplete and hence it was updated in C11 since it only contains the term ```object``` and not ```scalar object```?

Comment: @NirajRaut *"object"* is to be understood as single entity here, because an array does not have "*its stored value"*. Nonetheless, An array is compound of single objects with different values. - At the end, You modifying single objects with `scanf()` statement, thus the behavior shall be undefined. - But this is such a huge and intersting question on its own, that it can´t be answered and shouldn´t only reside here. - Ask a separate focused question about that. I´m very curious about the answers there, too.

Comment: Please tell me whether ```%c``` expects a ```char``` or an ```int```?

Comment: @NirajRaut I was wrong before. I apologize. `%c` expects an argument of type `char*`. - The `EOF` case with storing characters in `int` suprisingly doesn´t have side influence on here. But `char` is still compatible with `int`.

Comment: I feel that you were right before. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55009814/13469230

Comment: @NirajRaut Things are sometimes different for `scanf()` than for `printf()`. This is one of those cases. `scanf()` really expects `char*` for `%c`. Here is a test case: https://godbolt.org/z/dBpd8-

Comment: That's true for ```scanf()```. But my question is can I pass a negative ```int``` in the case of ```printf``` since while printing it's converted into an ```unsigned char``` — like ```printf("%c", -65);``` — I tried it on GCC but not getting the correct output.

Comment: @NirajRaut Where is the relation to this question?

Comment: Don't ask for a relation. Just answer it as I cannot ask more questions now. I did not even know that I can ask only 6 questions in 24 hours.

Comment: @NirajRaut You cannot print negative ASCII codes in `char` notation because there are none. All ASCII values are positive. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690415/negative-ascii-value What do you want to achieve with that statement?

Comment: Then how does ```%c``` expects an ```int``` in ```printf```. Shouldn't it expect an ```unsigned int```?

Comment: @NirajRaut The magic happens here just because of `EOF`. It is not a character, rather an symbol to indicate an error returned by a function. - To differentiate the error from common characters it had to be a negative value. The exact negative value of `EOF` is implementation-defined.

Comment: Hey, if there are no negative values what is ```signed char``` then?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [c11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), "Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types. Array and structure types are collectively called aggregate types"

So no, `b` isn't a scalar because it is an array.  If it were a number or a pointer (like `char* b`), it would be a scalar type.