# I tried to execute the following code on code blocks, where instead of getting the marks as 92.5 I get 0.000000

Tags: c, data-structures, floating-point

why I am getting 0.000000 as marks instead of 92.500000? Is there something to do with float in structures or something wrong in my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    int roll_no;
    float marks; 
};

int main()
{
    struct student s={"nick", 20, 52, 92.5};
    print(s.name,s.age,s.roll_no,s.marks);
}

void print(char name[],int age,int roll_no,float marks)
{
    printf("%s %d %d %f\n",name,age,roll_no,marks);//output:nick 20 52 0.000000
}
```

Comment: Declare the function before you call it. And pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but the whole point of using a `struct` is to make it more convenient to pass related information around as a bundle.  So I would declare the `print()` function as taking one argument, either of type `struct student` or pointer to `struct student`.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize - if you didn't see a compiler error then adjust your settings - the bad settings are  causing you to waste time by running erroneous code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is very subtle, but the compiler should be able to give you a warning about it (if not then you need to enable more warnings).

The problem is that you haven't *declared* the function `print` before you call it. That means the compiler will assume all numeric arguments have basic types, subject to the [default argument promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775). This will lead to *undefined behavior* when you later define the function using different argument types.

You need to declare (or define) the function before you use it:

```
// Declare the function
void print(char name[], int age, int roll_no, float marks);

int main()
{
    struct student s={"nick", 20, 52, 92.5};
    print(s.name,s.age,s.roll_no,s.marks);
}

// Define (implement) the function
void print(char name[], int age, int roll_no, float marks)
{
    printf("%s %d %d %f\n", name, age, roll_no, marks);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but one correction: the compiler will assume that all arguments have *the types you actually passed*, and subject to the "usual argument corrections".  Or, in this case, `int print(char*, int, int, double);`

Comment: @SteveSummit: It is the *default argument promotions*, per C 2018 6.5.2.2 6. They perform the integer promotions and promote `float` to `double`.